# OS image provided by GCE are maintained version or archived versions of OS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am a new user of GCE. According to this documentation here:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-repository
To install Docker Engine - Community, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7. Archived versions aren’t supported or tested. Are all the OS versions offered by the GCP maintained or archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Public images are provided and maintained by Google, open-source communities, and third-party vendors.
>
> Community-supported images are not directly supported by Compute Engine. It is up to the project community to ensure that images work with Compute Engine features and that security updates are maintained. Community-supported images are provided as-is by the project communities that build and maintain them.

So, yes if it is a public image you want to use, it is maintained. If you want to use a custom image they are not directly supported.

To check the Public images offered by Google Cloud Platform you can go in **Compute Engine > Images**.